# CSS overflow positioning

Tags: positioning, css

This is quite a hard problem to describe so I think this diagram will help:

[image: http://i41.tinypic.com/esvjgp.jpg]

this is the setup-

```
.column {position: absolute; width: specific;} // each positioned with javascript
.post {position: relative; margin: specific; width: either 100% or specific;}
```

The question is if the first post exceeds the width of its column, how can I make posts in another column react and only start under the larger post? I only need it to work with the first one, and I don't think floating the posts makes a difference. I know this can be done with javascript without much trouble, but the posts expand on hover so it'll be much nicer in css. Is there any way to do this? Do I have to change the position style of the column? Or is it only possible with js?

I'd appreciate any response even if you can't think of a solution.

Comment: Have you tried floating them and applying clear: left to the posts?

Comment: Given that everything's positioned with JavaScript, I think we'd need to see that script. Also, an example diagram of how you'd expect the output to look would be helpful. If you're unable to post a second image due to rep, just add the link to the image as text, and I, or someone else with sufficient rep, will add the image to your question.

Comment: It can be done trivially with floats: http://jsfiddle.net/VPF4F/2/ , no idea why you need relative or absolute positioning for this ? is this some kind of experiment ?

Comment: basically it's for a tumblr theme with options for the amount of columns and space between posts and width of posts, so it's just easier positioning everything and setting the container width with js and three values rather than the insane amount of css it'd require; this is also why the structure and order is rather stringent.
I have since just made it work with javascript instead, kind of, and some of the columns are relative and some are absolute. see here http://elphinstonetheme.tumblr.com/

Comment: @DavidThomas that photo is what I'd like the posts to be positioned as, with the html in that structure. As for the javascript, it won't make much sense without all the code, but here it as it is now (read comment above for changes):

Comment: `function setPos(col, wid, mar) {
 width = parseInt(col*(parseInt(wid)+parseInt(mar))+parseInt(mar));
 $('#content').css('width', width);
 if (elphinstone.first) {
  if (col > 2) {$('#col1').css('margin-left', parseInt(mar)+2*(parseInt(wid)+parseInt(mar)));}
  if (col > 3) {$('#col2').css('margin-left', parseInt(mar)+3*(parseInt(wid)+parseInt(mar)));}
  }
  else {$('.col').addClass('rel');}
 if (width > $(window).width() && col > 1) {elphinstone.colcount--; $('.col:last').remove(); setPos(elphinstone.colcount, elphinstone.postwidth, elphinstone.postmargin);}
}`

Comment: `if (elphinstone.index) {setPos(elphinstone.colcount, elphinstone.postwidth, elphinstone.postmargin);}`

Answer (score 0):

If you want a nice solution to multiple divs changing places and what not, then david desandro's masonry js plugin could be for you:

http://masonry.desandro.com/

You would have to utilize floats and let the plugin do the rest though. Apply the isResizable and isAnimated options (isResizable = true;, isAnimated = true;) when calling the plugin into effect and that should do it.